# How to find a product key

Tags: windows-8

I downloaded some sketchy software and it started downloading random apps all over the place on my computer. I tried a reboot, and now my computer is asking for my product key. I tried clicking the X and cancel buttons but they won't work. I have a iPod though. Is there a website or app where I can see what my product key is on my iPod? Any solution that doesn't involve calling Microsoft or spending money works for me really.

Comment: could you please specify type of your computer?

Comment: It sounds viral too me.  Try a virus scan.  Honestly it is in your best interest to wipe the harddrive and reinstall Windows.

Comment: My computer is an Asus and I cannot perform a virus clear. If you understood I cannot exit the page. So basically unless I get the product key, I can never use my computer again

Comment: Please stay in contact with me until I say the problem is fixed or you give up

Comment: You don't need your iPod. The Windows DVD/CD that came with your licensed copy of Windows or the OEM license number that came on your PC manufacturer's restore disk has that number. It's usually printed on a sticker attached to either the jewel case or paper sleeve that the disk came in. If you don't have it, Asus support can provide it given your computer's serial #.

Comment: I bought my computer with Windows pre installed. I hope that shines some light on the problem

Comment: If it is a laptop see at it's back there will be a sticker with key on it just opposite to processor sticker.

Comment: @KenWhite "The Windows DVD/CD that came with your licensed copy of Windows or the OEM license number that came on your PC manufacturer's restore disk has that number." - This is 100% false. Windows 8.x+ machines license key is embedded in the ACPI table stored on the firmware of the device.

Comment: @Anonymous - You don't need to view your Windows 8 product key in order to install it again.  Just boot to the same version of Windows 8 installation disk, you currently have installed, and install Windows 8.  You can also "Reset" your installation and achieve the exact same result.

Comment: @Rohitkr - "If it is a laptop see at it's back there will be a sticker with key on it just opposite to processor sticker." - This is 100% false.  Windows 8.x+ machines license key is embedded in the ACPI table stored on the firmware of the device.

Answer (score -3):

There are lots of free utilities out there, that can retrieve a bunch of product keys. They can be found out by simply asking the same question to Google. However I'll link you to one of them:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html